# Node express: dynamically creating a full body link with all attributes?

Tags: node.js, express

In a node-express app, I made a function to generate public links, for in this case I want to show a login-link in a view "http://example.net/login/123/tokenishfoobaarchinsignsignisgn"

```
function link_to(req, path){
  return `${req.protocol}://${req.hostname}/${path}`
}
```

This works OK in production where port is 80 by default.

Though I'm not finding a method on req where I can fetch ports to see if PORT != 80?

I would like to be able to have this know if I'm accessing via localhost:3001 for instance, to be able to add this to link-function. And/or is there a better way to have this type of link-generator functionality from express?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try using `req.get('host')` to get the port?

Comment: @GillesHeinesch that works! it gives me "localhost:3001", instead of just "localhost" from req.hostname. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK port is not available on the `req` object (the rest of what you need is). Normally you know what port your listening on because you provide it to express via the call to [listen()](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.listen), although it's possible to not provide in which case a random port is assigned.

If you need the port, you can get it from the [HTTP Server](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_server) instance returned from `listen()`:

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express()
var server = app.listen() # Random port is assigned if not provided as 1st arg.
console.log(server.address().port)
```

Comment: Ah, thanks for reminding me I'm actually calling bin/www file to boot the app; all the gold was in there!